# Verb used with 'calm'

Tags: verb-usage

I would like others to explain this to me.
Which sentence is correct?

1- He transmits calm.
2- He conveys calm.

Comment: We'd normally use the explicitly noun-based form ***calmness*** in such contexts. Note that ***transmit*** is more than a bit "odd" here. Common alternatives to ***convey*** include more obviously "figurative" verbs such as, for example, [*He **radiates** calmness*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+radiates+calmness%22) and [*He **exudes** calmness.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+exudes+calmness%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb **transmits** would be odd there, as it is normally used with radio signals and messages.  **conveys** is the idiomatic choice.

P.S. I see no problem with **calm** as  a noun.

Comment: It's also just as acceptable to write the sentence it like, "He is calming." :>

Comment: That would mean something a little different.

Comment: In the context of this individual being described as someone who [brings calmness to others](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/soothing), you could use ['calming'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=calming&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) by itself as a verb 0: